# Importing Excel sheet to DataTable

Tags: excel, interop

I need to import the contents of an excel file, into a DataTable, with first row of the excel behaving as a header row.
I can't use OleDB, because it alterd the data while importing, so the best would be to do this import using Excel Interop (i have excel installed on the machine), but I don't want to import the cell's value but the cell's text property.
The reason is that i have codes like "543523564537567457657567345" in the excel file, that are not formated to a specific type, and if i import the value, will probably be converted to a exponential number.

The other thing is that i want to be as fast as posible. (in my previous interop was much much slower that oleDB import)

Any ideas, advices or code samples i could use ?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What minimum version of excel are you targeting? If you are dealing with Excel 2007+ you should look into OpenXml and the OpenXml SDK

Comment: Hi Scott! i need it to work with excel 2003

Comment: Apparently that is also possible: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/how-to-use-xml-in-excel-2003-HA001101964.aspx

Answer (score 0):

From the Excel 2003 specifications [page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx), the maximum number precision is 15 digits. If the value 543523564537567457657567345 wasn't treated as text when entered into Excel then the best you will be able to retrieve is 5.43523564537567E+26. The `Text` property shows the displayed value of the cell with reference to the current number format whereas the `Value` property shows the actual stored value. Neither of these can be used to restore lost precision in excess of the 15-digit limitation.

If the value was not originally treated as Text by Excel then you won't be able to retrieve the lost precision. To be treated as text when entered via the UI, the value must be added to a cell which had Text format before the value was entered or the value must be added to a General format cell with the value preceded by a single quote. To be treated as text when entered via VBA, the value must be enclosed in double quotes.

Looking at the stored value in the XML produced from the spreadsheet will also shows you the underlying data. In this example I stored the same value in A1 and A2 but A1 was treated as a number whereas A2 was treated as text and you can see the difference in the XML fragment below (look at both the `ss:Type` and the `x:Ticked` parameters - see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140066%28v=office.10%29.aspx#odc_xmlss_ss%3adata)):

```
<Worksheet ss:Name="Sheet2">
  <Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="2">
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">5.4352356453756703E+26</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String" x:Ticked="1">543523564537567457657567345</Data></Cell>
   </Row>
  </Table>
 </Worksheet>
```

NB to quickly generate the XML for a specific `Range` in Excel, access the `Value` property as usual but pass the parameter `xlRangeValueXMLSpreadsheet` or its Integer equivalent of 11